# How to prevent Chrome extension from resetting options on browser restart?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, browser-extension

I am building my first Chrome extension. It works as expected so far, except one issue: The custom options users get to set keep getting reset to the default every time the browser closes and restart.

How would I prevent this so data is saved even after a browser restart?:

Options.js

```
    //On Submit
    updateArray("add",newSchedule, name, true,scheduleIdKey)

//Where I attempt to update storage data that is meant to stay store and save even if browser restarts
function updateArray(addOrDelete, site, listName, isObject, objectTargetKey=null, valueTargetKey=null, newValue=null){
  

  chrome.storage.sync.get(listName, function(data) {

    var array = data[listName]?data[listName]:[];

    if (addOrDelete == "add"){

      if(!array.includes(site)){
        array.push(site);
      }
    }

    var jsonObj = {};
    jsonObj[listName] = array;


    chrome.storage.sync.set(jsonObj, function() {
        console.log(data[listName]);
    });
  });
}
```

Background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    //create default schedule
    var defaultSchedule = {
    "active":false,
    

    }

    chrome.storage.sync.set({
        savedSchedules:[{"001":defaultSchedule}]

    });

})
```

Comment: Storage does not reset by itself. Only your code can do it. For example, in onInstalled you overwrite savedSchedules and it'll run each time you click the reload icon on the extension's card. There may be other places where you use `set` with the wrong value so use devtools debugger to set breakpoints and observe what's being written. Note that if you use console.log, don't forget JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value)) otherwise it won't show the real data.

Comment: So restarting the app runs `onInstalled` ? I'm not sure where this is occurring. Should I be using another function than `set`? What I provided in the question are the only places I am setting the storage so far. User enters options, submits and then background.js updates storage.

Comment: No, my comment says "it'll run each time you click the reload icon on the extension's card" so if you don't do it, the only solution is to debug it. Debugging should be one of the primary tools, anyway.

Comment: See the `reason` argument to the `onInstalled` handler: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#event-onInstalled